# Can we add a [jp.so] comment short code as an alias for [ja.so]?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, localization

Thanks to Sebastian for [pointing out the difference between country codes and language codes in a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411770/why-does-the-japanese-version-of-stack-overflow-use-ja-as-its-subdomain-instea?noredirect=1#comment869748_411770), and for pointing out that `https://jp.stackoverflow.com/` redirects to `https://ja.stackoverflow.com/`.

However, the comment short code `[jp.so]` does not exist and does not link to the Japanese site. Since I am more familiar with the `jp` country code than the `ja` language code (and [it seems](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411770/why-does-the-japanese-version-of-stack-overflow-use-ja-as-its-subdomain-instea?noredirect=1#comment869747_411770) I am [not alone](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411770/can-we-add-a-jp-so-comment-short-code-as-an-alias-for-ja-so#comment869787_411770)), I am converting this to a feature request:

Can we add `[jp.so]` as a valid short code for use in comments, expanding it to `https://ja.stackoverflow.com/`? I often type `[jp.so]` in comments out of habit and have to go back and fix them.

Original question follows for context.

---

I am aware of four localized versions of Stack Overflow:

- [Portuguese](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/), on the `pt` subdomain
- [Russian](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/), on the `ru` subdomain
- [Spanish](https://es.stackoverflow.com/), on the `es` subdomain
- [Japanese](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/), on the `ja` subdomain

Each of these [can be easily linked to in comments using a short form](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) that incorporates the subdomain: `[pt.so]`, `[ru.so]`, `[es.so]`, and `[ja.so]`.

The subdomains for the first three match the alpha-2 [ISO country codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_3166_country_codes) and [top-level domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Country_code_top-level_domain) for the countries after which the languages are named. However, the Japanese site does not: Japan's alpha-2 country code and TLD is `jp`, whereas the Japanese site's subdomain and associated comment quick-link use `ja`.

This can be somewhat confusing for people who are familiar with the standard code.

Was this a deliberate choice? If so, what is the reasoning? If not, can we make `jp` the official subdomain and leave `ja` in place as an alias?

Comment: I fail to see why it matters

Comment: This has tripped me up too.

Comment: Because `ja` is the _language_ code whereas `jp` is the country code. Also, `https://jp.stackoverflow.com/` already redirects to the `ja.` site.

Comment: "I fail to see why it matters"—partly, because I'm curious. But I do think it matters: there are standard codes for countries and some people are familiar with them. I often type the wrong short code when trying to help users find the Japanese site.

Comment: @SebastianSimon, [would you look at that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes)... I guess I assumed the language code would always match the country from which it originated.

Comment: @SebastianSimon, the redirect may be in place but the comment short-code doesn't work. That's actually the thing that bugs me; I'll update this now that I better understand what's happening.

Comment: This question has been asked before and the difference between `ja` and `jp` was explained — that’s how I know this —, but I can’t find it anymore. It was either in some comment or some deleted question or somewhere else entirely.

Comment: I've been part of the community for quite a while... FWIW, I _did_ search quite a bit for an existing question before asking this. If anybody can provide a duplicate I'd be happy to read through the existing answers.

Comment: If you are Brazilian I doubt you care about the country code for Portugal and are more interested in the language abbreviation. Really not clear why country codes are really that relevant at all

Comment: In all honesty, folks, will it hurt if we had another shortcut that addresses at least a little bit of a confusing mess we are all in? It's not like it is going to hurt if implemented, and it is not like we are delaying anyone by requesting it ( hint: take a look at the number of completed feature requests this year to truly grasp what I mean )

Comment: I(as would most) would expect `jp` and not `ja` for japan.

Comment: @TheMaster But it's not `ja` for Japan, it's `ja` for Japanese.

Comment: @TheMaster Should [es.so] not then become `[sp.so]`, `[mx.so]`, `[ar.so]`, `[bo.so]`, etc for each of the countries that speaks Spanish? Clearly doing it by language (i.e. `[es.so]`, `[ja.so]`, etc.) makes more sense.

Comment: @Llama There is no such country code as "sp"; "es" is both the ISO 639-1 code for Spanish, and the ISO 3166-1 code for Spain; the same is true for "ru" (Russian and Russia) and "pt" (Portuguese and Portugal). Because _most_ country codes match with their indigenous language code, and people are familiar with country codes from top-level domains, it is a common mistake. In this case, it's also a completely harmless one, since "jp" is not assigned as a language code, so there is no ambiguity (which is presumably why the domain name itself already redirects, as has already been pointed out).

Comment: @IMSoP Ah yes, my mistake with Spain.

Comment: @charlietfl It's not that country codes are relevant as such, it's that people are more familiar with them than language codes. So if someone tries to guess the language code for "Japanese", they may well choose "jp" rather than the correct answer, which is "ja". Nobody is going to guess that the language code for Portuguese is "br", so that example is not equivalent. Since "jp" is actually unassigned, automatically correcting people's mistake and linking to the correct domain does no harm, and saves people a bit of head-scratching.

Comment: There's a pretty chance this will come up again, especially with Chinese. Here are a bunch of primarily single-country languages whose names match up but codes do not (besides Japan `ja-JP`): Albania `sq-AL`, Armenia `hy-AM`, Belarus `be-BY`, China `zh-CN`, Estonia `et-EE`, Georgia `ka-GE`, Kazakhstan `kk-KZ`, Korea `ko-KR`, Kyrgyzstan `ky-KG`, Norway `nb-NO`, Ukraine `uk-UA`, and Vietnam `vi-VN`.

Comment: @Pluto unlikely though, considering that [SE currently stops accepting new localization of SE sites indefinitely](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20988/internationalization-state-of-the-stack).